# Configure timestamp format of kernel log?

Tags: kernel, logs

Is there a way to change the format of timestamp in kernel logs?

It was something like `2012-08-27T8:54:35.939421+03:00` now, I also checked `sysctl -a | grep log`, nothing found really.

Comment: jftr the timestamp are absolute numbers since boot and don't have anything to do with your system clock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, see the kernel code in `kernel/printk.c`, it's hardcoded as:

```
sprintf(tbuf, "[%5lu.%06lu] ", (unsigned long) t, nanosec_rem / 1000)
```

All you can do is enable/disable that timestamp. You can have whatever reads `/proc/kmsg` (syslog, klog...) add the timestamp itself.

Answer (score 0):

1. in `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/syslog`, it's automatically converted to HRTS (human readable timestamp).
2. With `-T`, `dmesg` can return you with the HRTS form of the kernel ring. Please look at `man dmesg`.
   You may make a cron script to get what you exactly want :
   every `$PERIOD` seconds, `dmesg --ctime --read-clear >> mymessagesHRTS.log`
3. You may think in using :
   `dmesg --console-off`
   `dmesg --ctime --decode --show-delta`
   (Reference : dmesg from util-linux 2.20.1)

hth - Stéphane